# How can I tell if "monerod" is working?

Tags: monerod

I tried running `monerod --data-dir g:\blockchain --no-igd` on Windows, using tallow to force all the traffic to go over the tor network.

I received the following log, and then there was just a pause and the database file does not appear to be growing and nothing appears to be happening.  Is monerod doing something, or should I have seen more messages after this?  How will I know whether it is working?

```
2017-06-11 02:00:30.082 5792    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-06-11 02:00:30.108 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
2017-06-11 02:00:30.124 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-06-11 02:00:30.124 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-06-11 02:00:30.186 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2017-06-11 02:00:50.669 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 P2p server initialized OK
2017-06-11 02:00:50.670 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58 Initializing core rpc server...
2017-06-11 02:00:50.698 5792    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2017-06-11 02:00:50.700 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2017-06-11 02:00:50.700 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2017-06-11 02:00:50.759 5792    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:326 Loading blockchain from folder g:\blockchain\lmdb ...
2017-06-11 02:00:50.943 5792    WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Error attempting to retrieve a hard fork version at height 0 from the db: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-06-11 02:00:52.941 5792    WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:531    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2017-06-11 02:00:52.941 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:78    Core initialized OK
2017-06-11 02:00:52.941 5792    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:68 Starting core rpc server...
2017-06-11 02:00:52.942 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:73 Core rpc server started ok
2017-06-11 02:00:52.974 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78 Starting p2p net loop...
2017-06-11 02:00:53.984 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1098    [1;33m
**********************************************************************
The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. It may take up to several hours.

You can set the level of process detailization* through "set_log <level|categories>" command*,
where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING)

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
**********************************************************************
[0m
2017-06-11 02:00:53.989 [P2P7]  WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:531    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the `status` (just type `status` into monerod) command here?